# Migrate .net 1.1 aspx page into .net4.5 with Japanese characters

Tags: asp.net, .net, character-encoding, webforms, migration

I am working on a project to convert the current web application built using .Net 1.1 that is being migrated to .Net 4.5 using VS2013.

Most of the existing .aspx files (developed in .Net 1.1) have Japanese characters which are not displaying in the browser properly. When I open the .aspx page in EditPlus it shows the proper Japanese characters. Japanese characters in .cs files appear properly.

I have already changed the Unicode to UTF-8.

When I add a new file to the project and copy the content from the old .aspx file then the Japanese characters appear properly.

What am I missing here that would cause the characters to not appear properly in the browser?

Comment: Visual Studio has an option in `Save as` -> `Save with encoding`. There, you have two options regarding UTF-8, **UTF-8 with signature** and **UTF-8 without signature**. Maybe you have the *wrong* option in your filed from the .NET 1.1 solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is the browser receiving UTF-8? (In Firefox open *view page info*)

Check that the globalization tag of your Web.Config is set to UTF-8.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkak5b9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx